# Не могу войти под суперпользователем ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Не могу войти под суперпользователем в убунте. Ввожу в терминале:

```
russia@russia-desktop:~$ su
Пароль: 
su: Сбой при проверке подлинности
```

У меня всего один пользователь, т.е. я сам. Что делать?

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo -s
```

или

```
su <имя администратора>  
sudo -s
```

В данном случае именем администратора должно быть имя пользователя, который входит в группу админов